# How to compare arraylist items to mysql database using jdbc connection from Asynctask?

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc, android-asynctask

I am developing an android app in which I stored contacts in an array list.

How to compare this array list items to mysql database using jdbc connection from Asynctask and to check whether the user exist in database or not and store this contacts in a listview?

Comment: @devaldcool That was an extremely inappropriate comment. Keep your comments constructive or don't post them at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HttpUrlConnection or volley for sending requests from mobile to server with the url query parameters,and then pass the contacts in the url query as key value pairs. Then the corresponding PHP script fetches the contacts data from headers whether they are in GET or POST parameters.Then after comparing those paramaeters with mysql database ,if the data exists no new contacts are outputted or the contacts are stored on the server and displayed in listview.

Comment: Sorry , the most convenient way is the above described way I suggested. Tick the answer as right if u like it :)